# Unable to install Realm through cocoa pod in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

I want to test Realm mobile database and object server. I tried installing Realm through cocoa pod.

My Podfile looks like this

```
target 'try realm' do
  use_frameworks!
    pod 'RealmSwift'
```

When I try to install pod I get the following error

```
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup
./scripts/swift-version.sh: line 59: [: =: unary operator expected
No version of Xcode found that supports Swift 3.0.2
```

But I have run swift --version in terminal I get 
    "Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)" and I have Xcode version 8.2 beta installed on my mac

So why I am unable to install Realm?

Comment: Why do you have a beta version of Xcode?

Comment: @rmaddy Because my internet is not working properly and that is the latest version of Xocde I downloaded before connection went down.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have Xcode fully installed.